# Importing a .dat File Java

Tags: java, macos, import, io

I've searched the internet for roughly an hour and a half now, and I can't for the life of me figure out where I've gone wrong.. Help!!

My problem is that every time I try and run it I don't receive an error until it searches for the file and without fail, it replies "File not found." I'm on a MAC I think I'm typing the directory in properly but something is messed up..

(When opening numEven.dat)
For my input I've tried "numEven.dat" (placing the dat file in the same directory as the java file)

I've also tried "/Users/java/numEven.dat" and "Users/java/numEven.dat"
I know it is in that directory. What am I doing wrong?

**Main Class file:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StatDriver
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String fileName = "";
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        double[] array = new double[20];

        System.out.print("   Enter file name: ");
        fileName = scan.next();

        System.out.println("\n \n \n \n          My Grades - View Statistics");
        System.out.println("           ------------------------");

        // int valueCount = readFile(array,fileName);
        array = readFile(array, fileName);

        Stat stat = new Stat(array, array.length);

        // call each calc on Stat class and display results for each method
        stat.calcAvg();
        stat.calcMedian();
        stat.findMax();
        stat.findMin();
        // print the return values for each of the above out to the user
    }

    public static double[] readFile(double[] array, String fileName) 
    {
        int valueCount = 0;

        FileIO importFile = new FileIO ();

        importFile.main(array, fileName);
        System.out.println(array);

        valueCount = array.length;

        // return valueCount;
        return array;
    }

}
```

**FileIO class:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class FileIO
{
    public void main (double[] array, String fileName)
    {
        double [] num = new double[5];
        Scanner inFile;
        int i = 0;

        try
        {
            System.out.println(fileName);
            inFile  = new Scanner(new File("fileName"));

            while(inFile.hasNextDouble())
            {
                array[i] = inFile.nextDouble();
                i++;
            }

            inFile.close();
            for(int x = 0; x < i; x++)
                System.out.println("   " + num[x]);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println ("   File not found");
        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            System.out.println ("   array index too large");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by changing

```
 inFile  = new Scanner(new File("fileName"));
```

with

```
 inFile  = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
```

in the method `FileIO.main`

Other than that (having no link to the problem), you could make the method `FileIO.main` static, and take advantage of Java collections to avoid hardcoding the number of elements of the `double` you want to read from the file. In the same method you are declaring a variable `double[] num` but not using it at all.

Comment: Also, the `FileIO.main` method should have a different name.

Comment: Yeah completely forgot to talk about that one

Comment: Yeah completely forgot to talk about that one

Comment: Wow.. That was too easy. Thanks!Can't believe I missed that.

I'm not sure what you mean with "you could make the method FileIO.main static, and take advantage of Java collections to avoid hardcoding..." Would you be able to explain a bit more.

Same to you @JanDvorak, why should it have a different name, I'm assuming you mean different than "main?"

Comment: @BrillianceOfBen the `Main(String[])` and `Main()` methods are special in the sense they can become the entry points to your application. You should name methods by what they do. A `Main` method is expected to be called by the JVM. Yours is called by the application.

Comment: Try renaming it to `public static ... loadFile(...)` and call it as `FileIO.loadFile(...)`